# How to store json object one by one to json array by click?

Tags: json

I am trying to get three rows of data by successive click events .i want to group all data objects into a json object.Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

$("#previous-education-submit").click(function()

{
var quali=$("#previous-education option:selected").text();

```
             var qualification ={
                         educationType:$("#previous-education option:selected").text(),
                         institutionName:$("#InstitutionName").val(),
                         yearofPassing:$("#YearofPassing").val(),
                         majorSubjects:$("#MajorSubjects").val(),
                         percentage :$("#Percentage").val(),
                         boardofStudey:$("#BoardofStudey").val()}
                        qualification= collectObjects(qualification);
                        console.log(qualification);
                });
                // Group JSON Data objects
                function collectObjects(qualification){
                    console.log(qualification);
                    return  qualification.concat(qualification);                    
                }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be like this, qualification= collectObjects(quali);

Comment: var course=[qualification:{}];create as global object